# Why are faculty positions in Management Information System (MIS) going down?

Tags: phd, early-career

A few years ago, for every fresh PhD graduate in Management Information System (MIS), there were three open faculty positions. Then the ratio of graduates to positions dwindled to 1:2, then to 1:1.5, later to 4:1. Finally, MIS departments all over started shutting down or being merged into Management, Operations or other departments and today hardly any schools offer a PhD in MIS.

It is possible that there are still many fields where for every PhD graduate there are two, three or more open faculty positions. Are there any areas with faculty shortages these days? Animal Sciences? Genetics? Psychology? Sociology? Wildlife Sciences? Mechanical Engineering? Computer Science? Statistics? Any field at all?

Comment: well, I can tell you that's a negative on psychology

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's due to economy.

Comment: Here's a little exercise you can do: estimate how many Ph.D.s are produced per faculty member over the course of that faculty member's career. Assume some fraction of these students want faculty positions.  Calculate the expected number of open faculty positions per Ph.D. graduate. You write "A few years ago for every fresh PhD graduate in Management Information System (MIS), there were three open faculty positions." If so, it implies that the field is (was) very new, which is the way around the "equilibrium" above.

Comment: Having a faculty positions to PhD graduates ratio of more than 1 is very very unusual. It only happens if there is a new and extremely hot area. Inevitably the ratio will return to normal which is considerably below 1.

Comment: Possibly engineering and other professional disciplines where the private sector pays vastly more than the typical academic appointment.

Comment: I believe in economics they call this "supply and demand". High demand + low supply (new field) --> lots of people enter the field --> high supply + high demand --> positions rapidly filled, but many people still in pipeline --> low demand + high supply --> fewer jobs to go around.

Comment: Another point is the reduction of direct state-provided research funding. Temporary PhD or PostDoc positions can have funding allocated and at the end, there is no obligation to keep this people on if the funding dries up. In contrast, a researcher with a permanent position will still need to be paid. (Though more and more of these positions are also dependent on obtaining funding...) - Add to that, the direct cost of employment for a PhD-student or PostDoc is also lower than for permanent faculty staff.

Comment: I mean as an overall trend the best explanations are the adjunctification and corporatization of higher ed (at least in the US)

Comment: @Raghu Parthasarathy this should be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

At least for central Europe, the number of faculty positions is definitely going down, but instead there is more money for project-based PhD positions. Unfortunetly these are usually just for three years, a timespan in which, at least in my field, most students are not able to finish. So PhD students employed in a project often become project hoppers or are unemployed towards the end of their PhD.

In general, this development from faculty positions to project-based positions is not all bad, since it requires the PIs and professors to constantly improve. The downside is the time lost for writing grant proposals and the uncertainty if a position will be funded or not.

Comment: I don't think this answer applies to all fields and all countries.  Can you be more specific about where your answer comes from?